# How to overload bitwise operator without affecting operands?

Tags: c#, overloading, bitwise-operators

I have the following function:

```
    public static Hex operator&(Hex a, Hex b)
    {
        Hex toReturn = a;

        byte aByte = ConvertStringHexToByte(a._value);
        byte bByte = ConvertStringHexToByte(b._value);
        aByte &= bByte;
        toReturn._value = ConvertByteToStringHex(aByte);

        return toReturn;
    }
```

I don't pass values by references, however it seems the first operand is changed?

I want to be able to do

c = a&b

without a or b to be changed.

where do I go wrong?

Comment: I'm afraid I rejected your edit suggestion for my answer. I personally wouldn't go so far as to say that `Hex` isn't worth defining, especially not if it saves you from a lot of repeated work. I would, however, caution you to check if you need to store this value as a string, or if it's better stored as a `byte` value. You could have a `Hex.Parse(hexString)` static method and a `.ToHexString()` instance method, for example. Ultimately: store the value in the format you will access it most in.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer!! Actually it's half/half string and byte. Sometime int but rarely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `Hex` is a reference type (a class), this line copies the reference to the same object in memory:

```
Hex toReturn = a;
```

Now `toReturn` and `a` both reference the same object. That is to say that the same object can be mutated by using `toReturn` or by using `a`.

You should create a new instance of `Hex` to store the result. For example:

```
public static Hex operator&(Hex a, Hex b)
{
    Hex toReturn = new Hex();

    byte aByte = ConvertStringHexToByte(a._value);
    byte bByte = ConvertStringHexToByte(b._value);
    aByte &= bByte;
    toReturn._value = ConvertByteToStringHex(aByte);

    return toReturn;
}
```